# disable the Clear Data button in android applications settings- manageSpaceActivity not working in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, manifest, android-applicationinfo

I'm working on an android game in Unity game engine. I want to disable Clear Data button in Android's Application Info of Manage Application to prevent user from clearing the application's data. In Android Studio I use `manageSpaceActivity` in the Manifest.xml file and it works fine.

<application
...
android:manageSpaceActivity=".ManageSpaceActivity">

But in unity when I add this code to `[ProjectName]/Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml` it does not work.
So, my question is where should I add `android:manageSpaceActivity=".ManageSpaceActivity"` in unity's AndroidManifest.xml file?